# This is why they call me "Book Smart"

Tags: story, steganography

So, I was walking alon g, bothering nobo dy one day when, out of nowh ere, this c razy person came out of a bookshop and t hrew a book ca lled 'Tolerance' at me. It broke my sp ine. That's when I lea rned the meaning of the exp ression.

> What was the lesson that I learned?

Hint:

> The paragraph has exactly 234 characters, plus the final "n" and "." which are extraneous. Does this help?

Comment: All I've got is [this](https://new.wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=NOHCTAPAPGDERHLIRR&t=500&a=n) ... wrong track?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Wrong track.

Comment: 444112233....wrong track?

Comment: @Brandon_J Wrong track.

Comment: Hmmm...is the book title relevant at all?

Comment: @Brandon_J No, "Tolerance" is just an ironic title for the thrower of books and breaker of spines to have used.

Comment: I see 235.  is this because the last word used to be misspelled?

Comment: @Rubio Crap. Yes. Thank you! I've revised the hint.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The expression is:

> WORDS HURT

There are:

> nine words that have a conspicuous space in the middle of them.  Splitting the story into nine lines, plus two extra characters off the end, yields
>  [image]
>
>  Taking the A1Z26 of the location of the spaces in the lines yields:
>  23 15 18 4 19 8 21 18 20 -> WORDSHURT

Comment: That’s a GROANER! +1 and I wish it could’ve been +2 for you and for Chowzen

Comment: Excellent! I'm still trying to figure out why @Soltius wasn't able to follow through; they were on the right track, indeed. I'll start forging a green checkmark for you and will hand it over when it's done.

Comment: Congrats ! Wasn't able to come through because it was 1AM in my timezone, had to get up at 7 and extra spaces were starting to dance before my eyes..

Comment: FWIW: Partially inspired by [this moment from the movie *Saved!*](https://youtu.be/umLUKBlpyoY?t=98)

Answer (score 6):

Partial after hint :

> The answer we're looking for has 9 letters, ans the text has 234 characters, which is 26 times 9. 26 is the number of letters in the alphabet.

Moreover,

> Extra spaces in text seem to be spaced evently such that the first space is between 0 and 26 position, the second between 26 and 52 etc.

So,

> I tried counting the position in the sentence where the spaces appeared (mod 26) and get letters from the positions gathered that way (eg first space appears as 23rd position > W), but it led me no where.

Comment: Feels like you got it. Maybe rot13(Ivtarer jvgu gbyrenapr nf gur xrl?)

Answer (score 3):

I have a few ideas. The following is a format of the question that I think will be useful to us.

```
SoIwasWalkingAlon gBothering
             nobo dyOneDayWhen
        outOfNowh ere
            thisC razyPersonCameOut
  ofABookshopAndT hrewA
           bookCa lledToleranceAtMe
      itBrokeMySp ineThatsWhen
             ILea rnedTheMeaning
         ofTheExp ression
```

My guess is that

> The answer consists of nine letters, and is clued by its relative location to the inserted spaces. The **first** letters **b**efore (**1B** for convenience) the splits spells "nohctapap". Not helpful. First letter *after* (1_A_) spells out "gderhilierr." **2A** - "byrarllne". **3A** - "ooezeeees" - fun word, no help. **4A** - "tntywdtds". **2B** - "obwsdcsex". **3B** - "looinkyle" (we technically got "loo in kyle", but I sincerely doubt that this gibberish is the answer.) **4B** - "annhaomie".

To conclude, I *don't* yet have the answer, but I wanted to put my failed tries up for the benefit of future solvers.

Also - to Chowzen - Am I remotely on the right track, at least with the first sentence of the hidden text?

Comment: Yes to "nine," not really to "proximity." BTW, my sister's middle name coincidentally happens to be "looinkyle." :)

Comment: @Chowzen drat, I'll keep looking. Also, for the briefest moment I thought you were serious on the last part lol.

Comment: @Chowzen I edited the first sentence on the "not really" part.

Comment: Possibly relevant then that Tolerance is rot13(nyfb avar yrggref)?

Answer (score 0):

not it I'm sure, but

> A skip in nine breaks spine

But i do wonder

> if nine breaks is relevant

Comment: I applaud the effort (+1), but that's more like lateral thinking than steganography.